# using vlookup to find matching values in a column

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a column A with duplicate values inside it. I want to write a vlookup which does the following; If A has duplicate value inside it, the B value of this columns same row should be overwritten to previous A values same row in Column B.

An example for this ;

```
    A         B
1  Anna  | 23 years old
2  Anna  | 34 years old
```

So the value in B1 should be automatically 34 years old since the values in A column match.

How can i do this?

Comment: This is a contrived example, what is the real problem you are trying to solve?  Have you tried anything on your own yet?

Comment: i know how to find A column has duplicates, i dont know how to write the cell B2 into B1 if columns match

Comment: @YigitTanverdi Well, that's not exactly the original question. Anyway, if this is your only problem you can just use `Cells(1, 2) = Cells(2, 2)` or you might refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23668300/4934172) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this was just an example though, so the matching value can be in another cell like A10 or A100 (its not neccesarly in A2).

Comment: I know it was an example! you should be able to apply the same approach to any pair of cells (assuming you already got the positions of the two cells).

Comment: i dont know which cells match, the matching cells are variable. I dont know exactly which cells are matching

Comment: As you've given two columns as an example, does the real data have a date of birth column by any chance?

Comment: no it only has two columns; one is Name and the other one is age

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim dict1 As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim strFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String, copyVal As String

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  '-->get last row with data in column A
    'enter unique values of column A in dict1
    c1 = Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    For i = 1 To UBound(c1, 1)
        dict1(c1(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i

    For Each k In dict1.keys
        'find last occurrence of each value in dict1
        Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find(k, Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            'get column B value for found string
            copyVal = rngFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            Do
                'find all the occurrences of each value in dict1
                Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find(k, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
                'change value in column B for each occurrence
                rngFound.Offset(0, 1).Value = copyVal
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        End If
    Next k
End Sub
```

See image for reference:

[image]

**EDIT# 1**
**________________________________________________________________________________**

```
Sub Demo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim dict1 As Object, dict2 As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim strFound As Range, delRange As Range
    Dim strFirst As String, copyVal As String

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  '-->get last row with data in column A
    'enter unique values of column A in dict1
    c1 = Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    For i = 1 To UBound(c1, 1)
        dict1(c1(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i

    For Each k In dict1.keys
        'find last occurrence of each value in dict1 and save row number in dict2
        Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find(k, , xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            dict2.add rngFound.Row, 1
        End If
    Next k

    'check for column A if row number exists in dict2, if not then add to a range for deletion
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Not dict2.exists(Cells(i, 1).Row) Then
            Debug.Print Cells(i, 1).Address
            If delRange Is Nothing Then
                Set delRange = Cells(i, 1)
            Else
                Set delRange = Union(delRange, Cells(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'delete the range
    If Not delRange Is Nothing Then
        delRange.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT# 2**
**________________________________________________________________________________**

```
Sub Demo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim dict1 As Object, dict2 As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim strFound As Range, delRange As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range, rngFound1 As Range
    Dim strFirst As String, copyVal As String

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row  '-->get last row with data in column A
    'enter unique values of column A in dict1
    c1 = Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
    For i = 1 To UBound(c1, 1)
        dict1(c1(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i

    For Each k In dict1.keys
        'find first occurrence of each value in dict1
        Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(k, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        'find last occurrence of each value in dict1
        Set rngFound1 = Columns("B").Find(k, , xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
        If rngFound.Address <> rngFound1.Address Then
            rngFound.Offset(0, 1) = rngFound1.Offset(0, 1)
            rngFound.Offset(0, 2) = rngFound1.Offset(0, 2)
            If delRange Is Nothing Then
                Set delRange = rngFound1
            Else
                Set delRange = Union(delRange, rngFound1)
            End If
        End If
    Next k

    'delete the range
    If Not delRange Is Nothing Then
        delRange.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: that Looks perfect! only Thing is, after doing this, i want that the last "Anna" to be deleted from the row. So first 3 Anna's have the value 9 and Anna at A6 and corrosponding B6 values should be deleted.

Comment: I will have only 2 Anna's in my table, and last one should be automatically deleted after giving its value at Column B to previous Anna's  Column B

Comment: @YigitTanverdi - Do you want to delete the complete row?

Comment: yes, its going to be like only updating Anna's Age.

Comment: thanks a lot! final question, i actually said Column A but in my table the Anna Values are at Column B. Where in the code should i Change A to the B? There is also Height Column in Column C so if i want to also update this, how can i do this??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115794/discussion-between-mrig-and-yigit-tanverdi).

Comment: @YigitTanverdi - What's not working for you in above code?