# using vlookup for finding matching values

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have value in A1 and another value in B1. I want to use a vlookup which checks if there is any value equal to A1 in Column A. And if These values match then B1 gets the value of the matching row of A.

As an example if A1 has a value Student and A6 has value Student. Then B1 should get the value of B6.

```
=VLOOKUP(
```

I know we use sth like this but i dont know how to fill the condition. Does anyone have any Suggestion?

Comment: Wasn't answer to your [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048364/using-vlookup-to-find-matching-values-in-a-column) question helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`=ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,C:C,0),3)` where 3 is column C, you could use column(C1) here

Comment: i didnt get it. Why should i use Column C?

Comment: i Need to check if there is a duplicate in Column A and if there is any, Column B should get the value of the second A value's column B

Comment: You don't, change them to yours!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for cannot be done with a VLOOKUP. This is because if you are looking up a string in column A and using a reference from column A you will always return that string in column B, even if there is only one instance of that string. Unless that string did not exist in column A in the first place and then you would get an "#N/A".

The best way to solve your problem is to run a COUNTIF formula in column B, this will tell you how many instances of that string are found in column A.

Enter this into column B, and extend down:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

Add a filter to column B, and filter out any 1's to give you a complete list of all your duplicates in column A.

The above formula assumes that you have headings in A1 & B1, and your data begins A2.